# Unable to insert the data in Android SQlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

> I am unable to insert the records in Android Sqlite database,
>   exception thrown is shown below :

```
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403): Error inserting id=1 phone_number=999000 name=John
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1582)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at com.example.dbtest.DBHelper.insertContact(DBHelper.java:47)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at com.example.dbtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-28 14:22:08.781: E/Database(403):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 14:22:08.781: D/ContactsMaster ::(403): inserted
```

insertQuery function are listed below :

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }


public void insertContact(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_ID, "1");
        values.put(KEY_NAME, "Rajan");
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, "9990008973");

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
```

The code when executed return exception. Database is created successfully but i am not able to insert the records into it.

Comment: Remove this `values.put(KEY_ID, "1");` becoz your `KEY_ID` is primary key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `values.put(KEY_ID, "1");` it's because your `KEY_ID` is primary key. and primary key must be unique.

When you again insert a record then already one record found with older id. so, it' give constraint failed error.

Answer (score 1):

INTEGER PRIMARY KEY generates itself, you should not specify it. To solve your issue simply remove this row:

```
values.put(KEY_ID, "1");
```

If you want to get hold of the ID, it it is returned when you call [insert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) as a long like this:

```
Long id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

For more info about how to use SQLite in Android suggest you take a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) tutorial:

Comment: Actually, you *can* specify a primary key value, provided that it's unique or a conflict resolution algorithm is specified. Most of the time you just don't *want* to specify it.

Comment: @laalto Is it necessary to defined Primary key as `Auto Increment` in `SQLite`?

Comment: Yes that is true, but there is rarely a need for it. (Given these basic problems) I updated my answer, to fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @MD No, the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword just slightly changes how the id generation algo works. http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 1):

becuase when SQLite try to insert by ID if record ID has been exist take Error.

Try to use some solution:

1. New Function By No ID Argument and Add AutoIncrement into id

Add Auto Increment: `KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,`

Remove: `values.put(KEY_ID, "1");`

2. New Function By Last ID to insert
   [see this](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're wrong about KEY_ID. Primary key should be able to store anything as long as its unique for each row. 
One column can be primary key and not be autoincremented integer number and it should work just fine

But when you working in android its better if you define a columns named "_id" as your primary key. you get something like this.

```
String KEY_ID = "_id";
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER    PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined the ID Primary key you can't assign a value to it! just remove that part:

```
values.put(KEY_ID, "1");
```

It's highly recommended to add "AUTO_INCERMENT" to ID field in database for making unique IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
```

I had written this

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME  (" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
```